# Android: inputType none and physical keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a problem with TextEdit,
if I do `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NONE);` the user is not able to type anything.
Anyway, if there is a physical keyboard attached, then the user can type by using it (of course the soft keyboard doesn't work).

Is there any way to fully disable editing on a EditText?

PS: I need to do that programmatically at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`android:editable="false"` 
in xml layout file

Comment: Thanks, anyway I didn't say that I need to do that programmatically (at runtime)

Comment: You can use setFocusable(false); and setClickable(false); to make edit text non editable in Java code.

Comment: yes, it works!
I've tried with setFocusable and it works...
(tried only in the emulator though, but should work also on real devices, maybe I'll try soon)

Comment: i tested my code on real device only. If it is not working let me know i have one more solution.

Comment: Yes it works... anyway if you really want :P please post your other solution... Thanks @yugandhar-babu ! :)

Comment: why you need other solution, if above answer/suggestion is working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`android:editable="false"` is **deprecated** ,prefer not to use it.
Another solution to this that I used is given below

```
first_password_EditTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
first_password_EditTextBox.setEnabled(false);
```